# Where does the data live in a Multi-Container Dockerized application?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to build a couple of Docker images for different PHP-based web apps, and for now I've been deploying them to Elastic Beanstalk using the [Sample Application](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-docker-nginx-proxy) provided by AWS as a template. This application contains two Docker container definitions: one for PHP itself, and the other for Nginx (to act as a reverse-proxy).

However, it seems a little odd to me that the source code for my PHP application is effectively deployed *outside* of the Docker image. As you can see from the Github sample project linked above, there's a folder called `php-app` which contains all the PHP source files, but these aren't part of the container definitions. The two containers are just the stock images from Dockerhub. So in order to deploy this, it's not sufficient to merely upload the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file by itself; you need to ZIP this file together with the PHP source files in order for things to run. As I see it, it can (roughly) be represented by this visual tree:

```
*
|
|\
|  - PHP Docker Container
|\
|  - Linked Nginx Container
 \
   - Volume that Beanstalk auto-magically creates alongside these containers
```

Since the model here involves using two Docker images, plus a volume/file system independent of those Docker images, I'm not sure how that works. In my head I keep thinking that it would be better/easier to roll my PHP source files and PHP into one common Docker container, instead of doing whatever magic that Beanstalk is doing to tie everything together.

And I know that Elastic Beanstalk is really only acting as a facade for ECS in this case, where Task definitions and the like are being created. I have very limited knowledge of ECS but I'd like to keep my options open, in case I wanted to manually create an ECS task (using Fargate, for instance), instead of relying on Beanstalk to do it for me. And I'm worried that Beanstalk is doing something magical with that volume that would make things difficult to manually write a Task definition, if I wanted to go down that route.

What is the best practice for packaging PHP applications in a Docker environment, when the reverse proxy (be it Nginx or Apache or whatever) is in a separate container? Can anyone provide a better explanation (or correct any misunderstandings) of how this works? And how would I do the equivalent of what Beanstalk is doing here, in ECS, for a PHP application?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to build it.

The easiest is to have one service ecs with two container foreach web app (one container for php app and one container for nginx).
The only exposed port in each service is nginx 80 port with [ecs dynamic port](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/).
Each exposed service should have an [alb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) that redirect trafic to nginx port.

In this case nginx is not used as loadbalancer, only for front web server.

Edit:

Your DockerFile for php app should be like that:

```
...

# Add Project files.
COPY . /home/usr/src

...
```

And for dev mode your docker-compose:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  php:
    build:.
    depends_on:
...
    environment:
...
    ports:
...
    tty: true
    working_dir: /home/usr/src

   volumes:
      - .:/home/usr/src
```

Then in local use docker-compose and live edit your files in container.
And in production mode file was copied in container at build time.

Is it more clear?

Comment: Hey thanks sGeek, my question is more about where the data (i.e. PHP files) should live. Do I bundle them in the same container that has the PHP executable? Or do I put them in a third "data container"? Or is there some other way to do it... mounting them as a volume on the host machine for instance? (Which I think is what Elastic Beanstalk is doing)

Comment: php file is in your php web app container. In dev mode you share volume where your files are located and in production mode your file is copied when your build your image. Does respond to your question?